# Google Maps Javascript API v3 routes iteration

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am struggling with the Google Maps javascript API. I am trying to parse the DirectionsResult by myself to display some data and later on pass them to database.

However the iteration through loop

```
for (i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++)
{ var route = response.routes[i];`
```

Doesn't seem to catch up with all the data provided from routes[i]. I am trying to display route summaries but can't get any but route[1] summary out, if index is defined with i. If I am defining routeIndex with a number it works just fine.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js&libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var map = null;
    var boxpolys = null;
    var directions = null;
    var routeBoxer = null;
    var distance = null; // km
    
    function initialize() {
      // Default the map view to Finland.
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.25, 25.35),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        zoom: 5
      };
      
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      
      directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 
       map: map
      });      
    }
    
    function route() {
      
      var request = {
        origin: "Sastamala+Finland",
        destination: "Tampere+Finland",
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true
      }
      
      // Make the directions request
      directionService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
         directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
         parseJson(response);
         console.log(response);
                       
        } else {
          alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
 
  // Parse JSON

  function parseJson(response) {
     for (i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
          var route = response.routes[i];
           // Route atribuutit
         // Push alternative routes to results div 
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += route.summary; 
  console.log(route.summary);                    
          for (j = 0; j < route.legs.length; j++) {
             var leg = route.legs[j];
             // Leg atribuutit
               for (k = 0; k < leg.steps.length; k++) {
                   var step = leg.steps[k];
                // Steps atribuutit
                  
            }
        }        
    }  

}   // End of JSON parse
  </script>
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 90%;
      width: 70%;
      float: left;
    }
    #results {
      height: 90%;
      width: 30%;
      float: right;
    }

    #controls {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 11pt;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="initialize();">
   <div id="controls"></div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="route()"/>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
```

I know DirectionsResult.routes.summary isn't documented anymore but DirectionsRenderer can provide the same functionality as "Suggested routes" so it should be possible to make.

**UPDATE1**: I updated my code by taking all unnecessary things away. The code returns the array of 2 routes, which I can see from the console, but when I am trying to display the summary for each route, it always displays only route[1].summary, which is "Sastamalantie/Reitti 249 ja Porintie/Reitti 11" wheres route[0].summary is "Reitti 12" and is not displayed. The same thing outputs in both cases:
1. `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += route.summary;`
2. `console.log(route.summary);`

**UPDATE2**: Provided answer solved my issue but I came across for another problem concerning the same iteration loop.

```
      // Make the directions request
  directionService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        parseJson(response);
        console.log(response);
        google.maps.event.addListener(directionsRenderer, 'routeindex_changed', function() { 
        console.log(this.getRouteIndex());
    });

    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });
}

    // Parse JSON

    function parseJson(response) {
    var resultsHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
        var route = response.routes[i];
            // Route atribuutit
            route.overview_path;
            var pathPolyline = route.overview_polyline;
            var routeName = route.summary;  
                resultsHTML += "<p onclick='directionsRenderer.setRouteIndex(i)'>" + (i+1) + ": " + routeName + " ";    
                console.log(routeName);  // setRouteIndex(i) returns always 3.                  
        for (j = 0; j < route.legs.length; j++) {
            var leg = route.legs[j];
                var routeDistance = leg.distance.text;
                var routeDuration = leg.duration.text;
                    resultsHTML += routeDistance + " " + routeDuration + "</p>";
            // Leg atribuutit
                    for (k = 0; k < leg.steps.length; k++) {
                    var step = leg.steps[k];
            // Steps atribuutit     
        }
    }        
}
    // Push alternative routes to results div
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = resultsHTML;
```

I am now getting the route.summary displaying like it should be but in line `resultsHTML += "<p onclick='directionsRenderer.setRouteIndex(i)'>" + (i+1) + ": " + routeName + " ";` when each `<p>` is clicked, `setRouteIndex(i)` returns to console value 3 and draws on map routes[3], wheres it should define for each `<p>` tag a corresponding routeIndex. However i+1 is displaying the right routeIndex number for each route eg. 1: route, 2: route.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I updated my 1st post, see above.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the output for the first route in the "results" div:

```
// this line clears out the "results" div
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
// this outputs the data from this iteration of the loop
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += route.summary;
```

Remove the first line (or move it outside the loop).

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var boxpolys = null;
var directions = null;
var routeBoxer = null;
var distance = null; // km

function initialize() {
  // Default the map view to Finland.
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.25, 25.35),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    zoom: 5
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function route() {
  var request = {
    origin: "Sastamala+Finland",
    destination: "Tampere+Finland",
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
  }

  // Make the directions request
  directionService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      parseJson(response);
      console.log(response);

    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });
}

// Parse JSON
function parseJson(response) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
      var route = response.routes[i];
      // Route atribuutit
      // Push alternative routes to results div 
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += i + ":" + route.summary + "<br>";
      console.log(route.summary);
      for (j = 0; j < route.legs.length; j++) {
        var leg = route.legs[j];
        // Leg atribuutit
        for (k = 0; k < leg.steps.length; k++) {
          var step = leg.steps[k];
          // Steps atribuutit
        }
      }
    }
  } // End of JSON parse
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
#results {
  height: 90%;
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}
#controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="controls"></div>
<input type="submit" onclick="route()" />
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="results"></div>
```